# Joomla 3.4.0 pagination

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have just updated to Joomla 3.4.0 and my pagination hack has disappeared.

Previously the number of (pagination) links to show could be edited in pagination.php but I can no longer find out where that file lives?

What's causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please include your code snippets

Comment: There is no code snippet. I am trying to find the code in the Joomla code base that controls the default pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered it is now stored here:

libraries/cms/pagination/pagination.php

Answer (score 1):

The pagination file you are talking about is in:

```
templates/your_template_name/html/pagination.php
```

In that file you can edit the following functions:

```
pagination_list_footer($list)
pagination_list_render($list)
pagination_item_active($item)
pagination_item_inactive($item)
```

You can find a proper tutorial [here](http://www.segida.com/website-development-blog/item/4-customizing-joomla-3-pagination)

Comment: Thanks but this isn't the core pagination file. Only in the core pagination file can you change the amount of pagination links that appear. It is set to 10 but I need to change it to 20.